# AWS CloudFront, `Vary` header and content negotiation

Tags: http, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to implement content negotiation based on client `Accept` headers so that clients that accept `image/webp` get webp images while clients that don't get plain old jpeg. webp and jpeg image are served from the same url, i.e. /images/foo-image/ and the content returned varies on the `Accept` header presented by the client. This now works great on my site.

Next challenge is to get this working AWS CloudFront sitting in front of my site. I'm setting the `Vary` header to `Vary: Accept` to let CloudFront know that it has to cache and serve different content based on the client `Accept` headers.

This doesn't seem to work unfortunately, i.e. CloudFront just serves up whatever it first gets it's hands on, `Vary` and `Accept` notwithstanding. Interestingly, CloudFront does seem to be able to vary content based on `Accept-Encoding` (i.e. gzip).

Does anyone know what gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this is [documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#ResponseCustomContentNegotiation) as not supposed to work:

```
The only acceptable value for the Vary header is Accept-Encoding. CloudFront ignores other values.
```

**UPDATE:** [AWS now has support for more sophisticated content negotiation](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/enhanced-cloudfront-customization/). I wrote a [blog post on how to take advantage](http://friism.com/webp-content-negotiation-cloudfront) of this.

Comment: Hello, it does not work for us despite we have white listed Accept, Authorization and Origin.

Answer (score 2):

Just to update this question, CloudFront now supports caching by different headers, so you can now do this