# Which CDN solutions support caching with content negotiation?

Tags: http, caching, cdn, cloudflare, content-negotiation

I'm serving a set of resources through **content negotiation**.
Concretely, any URL can be represented in different formats,
depending on the client's `Accept` header.

An example of this can be seen at Facebook:

- `curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://graph.facebook.com/daft-punk`

  results in JSON
- `curl -H "Accept: text/turtle" http://graph.facebook.com/daft-punk`

  results in Turtle

I'm looking for a **CDN** that caches content based on URL and the client's `Accept` header.

#### Example of what goes wrong

CloudFlare doesn't support this: if one client asks for HTML, then all subsequent requests to that URL receive the HTML representation, regardless of their preferences. [Others have similar issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510700/aws-cloudfront-vary-header-and-content-negotiation)

For example, if I would place CloudFlare over `graph.facebook.com`(and configure it to cache “extensionless” resources, which it does not by default), then it would **behave incorrectly**:

1. I ask for `http://graph.facebook.com/daft-punk` in JSON through curl;
   in response, CloudFlare asks the JSON original from the server, caches it, and serves it.
2. I ask for `http://graph.facebook.com/daft-punk` through my browser (thus in HTML);
   in response CloudFlare sends the cached JSON (!) representation, even though the original server would have sent the HTML version.

#### What would be needed instead

The **correct behavior** would be that CloudFlare asks the server again, since the second client had a different `Accept` header.
After this, requests with similar `Accept` headers can be served from cache.

Which CDN solutions support content-negotiation, and also cache negotiated content?

So note that only respecting *Accept* is not enough; negotiated responses should be cached too.

*PS1: It's easy to make your own caching servers support it. For instance, for nginx:*

```
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$host$request_uri$http_accept";
```

*Note how the client's `Accept` header is part of the key that indexes the cache. I want that on CDN.*

*PS2: It is not an option to use different URLs for different representations. My application is in the [Linked Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data) domain, where URLs play an important role for identification.*

Comment: The first thing that has to be fixed are the facebook server headers I think. They miss `Vary: Accept` which would tell the cache that the accept header influences the response.

Comment: @neo True, but still, it doesn't work for servers that correctly set the `Vary` header.

Answer (score 0):

Seems maxcdn still can set up custom nginx rules for content negotiation (despite what their faq says) - http://blog.maxcdn.com/how-to-reduce-image-size-with-webp-automagically/#comment-1048561182

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm unsure whether content negotiation works in general with MaxCDN or only when optimizing images. I will ask this.

Comment: Update: MaxCDN has confirmed they do _not_ support caching content-negotiated responses in general.

Answer (score -2):

I can't think of any way we would impact this at all at this time. We don't, for example, [cache HTML by default](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-). Have you actually seen an issue with this? Have you opened a support ticket?

Comment: I had created a support request (#68719) before I started this thread. The staff was very helpful, but they confirmed that CloudFlare does not support caching content-negotiated responses. They also said that it's "not on the near-term roadmap to add that".
The default is extension-based, so files with the `.html` _extension_ are not cached by default indeed (but this can be changed).
Issue: try caching any site with content-negotiation. Only the first-served representation is cached, and repeatedly served regardless of new clients' `Accept` header. Would this improve in the future?

Comment: Question updated with example of what goes wrong with CloudFlare (and others I've tested).